# Can I use a Max model with V-ray materials in Blender without too much trouble?

Tags: modeling, rendering, conversion

and sorry for the ultra noobie question but just learning to use Blender (or better said...a computer ) and I'm about to spend a rather steep amount of $ on a Max V-ray model from TurboSquid for my animations so I just want to know if I can actually use it in Blender?
(I'd love to make it myself but my modelling skillset is currently at Toddler level)
I just need this model bad. Haha.
I'm already totally in love with Blender...I don't know 3DMax but I've heard it's pricey.
Any help is seriously appreciated. Greetings.

Comment: Maybe you should learn a bit more about blender before spending money in assets you're not sure that will work?

Answer (score 0):

**You can** use a model from other application **if** the the model's file is in **OBJ, FBX,Dae or ABC**. **If the model is in 3DS Format**, which is a 3Ds Max format **you can't** use it unless you find a way to change the format (**OBJ, FBX,Dae or ABC**).

For the Materials, you need to make everything again with Blender Materials. As far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you both! Sounds like I need to learn to use 3DSMax also then just to make sure. The thing is the model...I just want that model even if it doesn't work in Blender I'll make it work somewhere else haha. Greetings and thanks again!!
I know enough.